# CSS menu not working in Safari in Mac

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, safari

Is there anyone can help to figure out why the css menu of website http://www.hkroboticsurgery.com work in Safari(version 5.1.7), IE and Chrome in my PC but fail to drop-down in Safari(version 5.1.10) of Mac?

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: works fine in chrome. add a screenshot.

Comment: yes, it work fine in Chrome, but not in Mac Safari.  I cannot figure out, please help.

Comment: can you add a screenshot so we can see what is failing and give you alternatives please?

Comment: If you hover +Home, +Liver or +Wound menu in Safari in Mac, submenu fail to drop-down.  But it work well in PC.